# How can i call a String from a method in a toSting() method (all methods are in same class)

Tags: java, methods, tostring

I've been stuck here for a while.
I want to call string `lesson` from the lesson method into my `toString()` method. Both methods are in the same class.

Here is lesson method:

```
public static String lesson() {
    System.out.println("Now you have written about your day, what are the lesson learnt ? Huh??");
    Scanner lessonLearned = new Scanner(System.in);
    String lesson = lessonLearned.nextLine();
    return lesson;
}
```

Here is the toString method

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String final = "";
    final = "[" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime() + "," +lessonShouldBeHere+ "," AnotherString  + "]";
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Need some context.  Otherwise, can't really give you a good answer.  What's the class that the lesson and toString method belong to?  What is the purpose of the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, `String lesson` is a local variable, and not accessible outside the context of the method (because it is on the stack and no longer exists).

```
static String storedLesson = null;
public static String lesson() {
    System.out.println("Now you have written about your day, what are the lesson learnt ? Huh??");
    Scanner lessonLearned = new Scanner(System.in);
    String lesson = lessonLearned.nextLine();
    storedLesson  = lesson;
    return lesson;
}
```

To solve this problem, make a static variable that holds the lesson value.  I suggest static because this is a static method.   If this method was a member method of a class, it would be better to make this a member variable.

Then use `storedLesson` in your `toString` method